# onclick changing colour of a link, and returning all others to default

Tags: colors, hyperlink, onclick

I have a list of links which open up various hidden divs on a page. Each link is white. Very simply all I want to do is when each link is 'active' it changes to yellow.

This is fine, and I've achieved this using an onclick event this.style.color='yellow';

the problem is that they then stay yellow, so effectively I need either a way to globally change all other elements back to white onclick OR to individually specify the each link to turn white

thinking javascript wise, could I achieve it with something like

onclick turn all links to white
turn this link to yellow

? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: The answer to "could I achieve it with something like `onclick turn all links to white turn this link to yellow`" is yes. But this probably does not help you. Post the code that you have and i can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use onclick event just use css active your problem will get solve,

```
<style>
a:active
{
color:yellow;
}
</style>
```

where your link is,

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

If you need any other help just let me know.

Comment: problem is all the links just point to # on the page, so not sure that will work

Comment: just try then let me know.